# Lisp x86_64 compiler producing incorrect output

Tags: assembly, lisp, x86-64, masm, callstack

I am writing a Lisp compiler that generates code for the x86_64 architecture, specifically for OS X. I am using Chez Scheme as a reference compiler to check that the compiler's output is correct. Chez gave an output of 32 for the expression below, but my compiler's code gave me an output of 8 (below the Lisp code). I cannot figure out why, and I cannot also figure out how to tweak the assembly to make it return the correct result. If you are well-versed in x86_64 (GAS, Intel syntax) could you give me some advice here?

```lisp
(define (f x y) (* (* y 2) (+ x 3)))
(define x (f 5 2)); expecting an output of 32
```

```
    .global _main
    .text
_main:
    push 2  # push argument to f
    push 5  # push argument to f
    call f
    mov [x + rip], rax
    mov rdi, rax
    mov rax, 0x2000001
    syscall
f:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    push 3  # push argument to +
    push [rbp + 16]  # push argument to +
    call plus
    push rax  # result of +
    push 2  # push argument to *
    push [rbp + 24]  # push argument to *
    call multiply
    push rax  # result of *
    call multiply
    mov rsp, rbp
    pop rbp
    ret

    .data
x:
    .quad 0
```

Here are the `add` and `multiply` functions:

```
.macro operator mnemonic
push rbp
mov rbp, rsp

mov rdi, [rbp + 24]
mov rsi, [rbp + 16]
\mnemonic rdi, rsi
mov rax, rdi

mov rsp, rbp
pop rbp
ret
.endm

plus: operator add
multiply: operator imul
```

Comment: You aren't removing the pushed arguments from the stack after your function calls (eg. with `add rsp, 16`).  Note that the standard x86-64 calling conventions normally pass arguments in registers rather than the stack.

Comment: What's the point of loading into RDI and RSI if you're passing on the stack anyway?  Just `mov rax, [rbp+24]` / `imul rax, [rbp+16]`.  Although a much bigger efficiency gain could be had by inlining simple instructions like `add` instead of push/call/ret, especially keeping the current "top of stack" in a register.  See [Are these the smallest possible x86 macros for these stack operations?](//stackoverflow.com/q/62542955).  Your code is like intentionally the slowest possible way you could do anything.  You spend as many instructions and as much code size on push/call as you would inlining.

Comment: @RossRidge Would I do `add rsp, 16` within the function after `pop rbp`, or after I call it?

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm not worried about efficiency here; I just want something that works. But your tip for making the operator macro more efficient was very helpful despite that.

Comment: You can't use `add rsp, 16` within the function because the return address is at the top of the stack, not the function arguments..

Comment: @RossRidge That makes sense. Putting it after the function call solved my problem, thanks!